# Terraform unable to update subscription

Tags: google-bigquery, terraform, publish-subscribe, google-cloud-pubsub, google-iam

I have terraform script defining a pubsub subscription pushing data to bigquery as below:

```
resource "google_pubsub_subscription" "my-subscription" {
  name              = "my-subscription"
  topic             = google_pubsub_topic.my_topic.name
  project           = module.my_project.project_id

  bigquery_config {
    table           = "my_dataset.my_table"
    write_metadata  = true
  }

  depends_on        = [
    google_bigquery_table_iam_member.pubsub_bq_data_editor,
    google_bigquery_table_iam_member.pubsub_bq_meta_viewer
  ]

  dead_letter_policy {
    dead_letter_topic = google_pubsub_topic.my_deadletter.id
    max_delivery_attempts = 10
  }
}
```

The script runs fine and created the subscription successfully. Subsequently, I made a couple of changes to the the script including

- Change target bigquery table from `my_dataset.my_table` to `my_raw_dataset.my_table`
- Change pub/sub subscriber account from default pubsub service account to a custom service account and grant the permission to underlying bigquery table.
- Renamed the resource name from `my-subscription` to `my_subscription` and resync the state by using `terraform state rm` and `terraform import` command.

When I tried to deploy the change, I received error:

```
│ Error: Error updating Subscription "projects/my-project/subscriptions/my-subscription": googleapi: Error 403: The caller does not have permission
│ 
│   with google_pubsub_subscription.my_subscription,
│   on segment.pubsub.tf line 29, in resource "google_pubsub_subscription" "my_subscription":
│   29: resource "google_pubsub_subscription" "my_subscription" {
```

I validated both my personal account and the service account used by terraform is having `role/owner` access to project `my-project`.

Would anyone be able to advise, please?

Comment: Can you confirm whether the service account providing authorization to Terraform has the role `roles/resourcemanager.projectIamAdmin`?

Comment: Thanks, managed to resolve the issue by granting editor role to the topic.

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer here is probably that you need to grant BigQuery permissions (BigQuery Data Editor & igQuery Metadata Viewer) to your pub / sub account.

See here: https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/create-subscription#assign_bigquery_service_account